# Can an axiom in FOL have recursion?

Tags: set-theory, recursion, axioms, convention

Lately, I've been interested in playing around with seeing how powerful a set theory can be with a single axiom. A while, ago I made this naive axiom schema; dubbed the **axiom schema of propagation** (ASP).

$$\forall X \forall Y \exists Z(\Lambda(X,Y,Z))$$
Where  $\Lambda$ is a logical condition recursively defined (informally) as

$$\Lambda(X,Y,Z):=(X=\emptyset\iff Z=\{Y\})\wedge\forall x\bigg[\Big(x\in X \implies \exists y(y\in Z \wedge\Lambda(x,Y,y))\Big) \wedge
\Big(x\in Z \implies \exists z(z\in X \implies\Lambda(z,Y,x))\Big)
\bigg]$$

Monstrosity aside, I've found that pairing this with [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) & the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set) alone is quite powerful. Despite $\Lambda$ being in the definition of itself, evaluating $\Lambda$ for sets of finite rank eventually halts when the left side of implications are false; meaning the right sides (that include the recursive part) needn't be deduced.

> Is such a recursive definition allowed/conventional?

---

If you're curious, essentially what I've attempted in this axiom schema is that for a given set $X$, for every point within all "levels" of $X$ where there is an empty set, I insert a given $Y$ 'inside' such empty sets. This new set is $Z$. Here is an example of the process, shown graphically as rooted identity trees.

[image: axiom of propagation]

Given $X$ and $Y$, this $Z$ is the unique set that satisfies $\Lambda(X,Y,Z)$

Note: I say *schema* because the version I was later working with replaces $(X=\emptyset)$ with an arbitrary condition $\phi(X)$, similar to that found in [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). Without that replacement this set theory only gives rise to singletons. I've left it out for brevity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this sort of recursion is not allowed in first-order logic. Remember that in general a first-order formula, thought of as a query, has to "work" (= make sense and have an answer) on every element of every structure. Recursive formulas of the type in the OP run into ill-foundedness problems in general - e.g. supposing $a=\{a\}$, should we have $\Lambda(\{a\},\{a\},\{a\})$ be true or false? More relevantly, suppose $M$ is an illfounded model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$; for $a$ not in the illfounded part of $M$, how should we understand $\Lambda(a,-,-)$?

That said, in the presence of a weak fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we *can* make sense of your principle in a first-order way. Specifically, we first whip up a set-theoretic implementation of basic graph theory, with which we can easily talk about the result of substituting a given tree for each leaf in another tree. Note that this is totally recursion-free: basically, we talk about a particular graph on a subset of the Cartesian product of the vertex sets of two given graphs. Then we prove that we can conflate sets with certain types of trees, namely the (internally) well-founded extensional ones; this requires Replacement, since basically what we're doing is going through the transitive closure. Combining these we get a purely first-order sentence which - again, in the presence of this weak axiomatic background - expresses what you're looking for. (And in fact this sentence is outright provable in this fragment.)

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to do some research on illfounded-ness; I haven't heard the term before. I feel like I'd expect $\Lambda(\{a\},\{a\},\{a\})$ to be true for $a=\{a\}$, but it seems un-deducible.